# Jest importing MomentJS to unejected React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, momentjs, jestjs

I have a ReactJS app with MomentJS (2.20.1) + MomentJS (0.5.14) Timezone.

I want to create unit tests for this .js file:

```
// dateHelper.js
import * as moment from "moment";
export function someFunc() {
   // some operations with moment.utc() and moment()
}
```

And this is my test file:

```
// dateHelper.test.js
const dateHelper = require("../dateHelper");

test("format date properly", () => {
    // ...
});
```

But I'm getting `TypeError: moment is not a function` error.

How I can import momentJS in dateHelper.js to make it working properly with Jest?

Comment: Calling a Module Namespace Object, such as that created by `import * as ns from 'm';`, is illegal JavaScript. It throws. Use `const moment = require('moment');` or `import moment from 'moment';`. Also, _avoid_ mixing `import`/`export` syntax with `require`/`exports`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad so you are suggesting me to "import" moment like this : `const moment = require("moment");` in dateHelper. This time I'm getting `TypeError: moment(...).tz is not a function` error. It's timezone plugin of Moment which is automatically imported by webpack.

Comment: I don't see where it says it will be automatically imported. Regardless, you cannot `import * as ns from 'm'; ns();`. It is required to throw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try:

`import moment from 'moment'`

assuming that you are using the moment node module

Comment: Getting "TypeError: (0 , _moment2.default)(...).tz is not a function" error. `tz()` function comes with Moment Timezone (https://momentjs.com/timezone/) which is automatically detected and imported by core 'moment' package's webpack configurations.

Comment: `import moment from "moment-timezone` looks like working. I'll do some tests to be sure that importing `moment-timezone` instead of `moment` won't break anything.